# How can I configure Geany to compile & execute a C++ program by a single key?

Tags: c++, configuration, geany

Geany offers the following key bindings:
Compile- F9
Execute- F5

But what I want is to compile and execute by a single key, say F3.
If compilation is successful only then the program executes, otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build->Build menu commands (or similar -- has been changed over some versions of Geany) and configure your own command. E.g. you could use something like `gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f" && "./%e"`

(above will most likely only work on Linux as AFAIK the && operator is not available on Windows)

Please check [documentation](http://geany.org/manual/#build-menu-commands-dialog) for this.

Comment: If the compilation result in error, I want the error messages to be shown in the compiler window, not in the popped up terminal window.

Comment: This is might another topic.